# How to use dojo debounce and throttle?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need an example of using `debounce` and `throttle` in Dojo version 1.10.4.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any examples in their documentation.

- http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojo/throttle
- http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojo/debounce

At the moment I am trying to debounce the following event with no success

... Using require `'dojo/on'`.

```
on.debounce(window, 'resize', 2000, function (event) {
    topic.publish('event/resize', event)
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: possibly related: http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`debounce` is not a method of a function. It is a function on its own, one that returns another function. You are supposed to call it with the function that you would like to get debounced, and get a debounced one back that calls the original one if applicable.

In your case, you'd call it on the `on` callback:

```
on(window, 'resize', debounce(function (event) {
    topic.publish('event/resize', event)
}, 2000));
```

Comment: which module should be imported with require... 'dojo/on/debounce', or 'dojo/debounce'? thanks

Comment: It's `dojo/debounce`, a standalone function that has nothing to do with `on`

Comment: `dojo/on/debounce` is a shorthand function for debouncing event handlers. @Bergi's example could be rewritten with `dojo/on/debounce` as

`var debouncedResize = debounce('resize', 2000);
debouncedResize(window, function (event) {
  topic.publish('event/resize', event);
});`